# IOException: socket write error

Tags: java, ojb

While editing one report I am facing this issue(all other reports are working fine)
don't know what goes wrong

org.apache.ojb.broker.PersistenceBrokerSQLException: 
* SQLException during execution of sql-statement:

--some sql statement(correct one)

- Exception message is [Io exception: Software caused connection abort: socket write error]
- Vendor error code [17002]

---adding stack trace as well

- Target class is 'com.dto.CurrentDTO'
- PK of the target object is [currentId]
  at org.apache.ojb.broker.util.ExceptionHelper.generateException(ExceptionHelper.java:256)
  at org.apache.ojb.broker.util.ExceptionHelper.generateException(ExceptionHelper.java:90)
  at org.apache.ojb.broker.util.ExceptionHelper.generateException(ExceptionHelper.java:71)
  at org.apache.ojb.broker.accesslayer.JdbcAccessImpl.materializeObject(JdbcAccessImpl.java:594)
  at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.PersistenceBrokerImpl.getPlainDBObject(PersistenceBrokerImpl.java:1504)
  at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.PersistenceBrokerImpl.getDBObject(PersistenceBrokerImpl.java:1548)
  at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.PersistenceBrokerImpl.doGetObjectByIdentity(PersistenceBrokerImpl.java:1671)
  at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.PersistenceBrokerImpl.getObjectByIdentity(PersistenceBrokerImpl.java:1643)
  at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.DelegatingPersistenceBroker.getObjectByIdentity(DelegatingPersistenceBroker.java:357)
  at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.DelegatingPersistenceBroker.getObjectByIdentity(DelegatingPersistenceBroker.java:357)
  at com.common.OJBUtil.findByPK(OJBUtil.java:104)
  at com.dao.AbsDAO.find(AbsDAO.java:55)

Comment: May be, then how I am able to access other reports(webpages), and not that particular one which is throwing error

Comment: The meaning of 'software cause connection abort' is explained in the MSDN pages linked in my answer in the duplicate. I have nothing to add.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error from your SQL driver, in this case presumably an Oracle one.

Please have a look at the [Oracle Tips of Burleson Consulting regarding ORA-17002](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_developer_vendor_error_17002.htm) (not affiliated). In case this does not help, please see also [Chrostph Jahn's tipp about the same error](http://www.christoph-jahn.com/?p=1074).

What the ORA-17002 basically means is that the listener can not be reached. This might be due to a wrong or incomplete hostname (try the fully qualified name of the host). Make sure that you are using the correct service name, port and hostname. Sometimes this error occurs due to the fact that you are using a hostname different to that which the listener is told to listen on. Bottom line: check that you are using exactly the same hostname, port and service name that your listener is configured to.

Without more information (read: the stack trace) it is impossible to be more specific.

Comment: added stack trace, please see may be helpful for answering.

Comment: He isn't getting an exception from his SQL driver. The exception isn't coming from an Oracle JDBC class. None of this will cause a connection reset. It will cause a connection refusal, or a connection timeout. Neither of your links works.

Comment: Checked the links - working. May be you have a problem with your connection?It is a vendor error. And as such generated by the driver as documented in "Handling SQLExceptions" in the "The Java Tutorials". An exception might well be generated by the driver and handed up all the way to the user classes, as you surely know.

Comment: is it possible that db connection got dropped, at server side? I am asking because i don't have db access otherwise i will check.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same datasource (technically speaking, not semantically)? The error code rather indicates that the connection isn't established in the first place.